# SQL function to change the column format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a staging table with a column `LastAnalysisAmount` (`varchar` data type) which contains values like this:

```
LastAnalysisAmount
-------------------    
    0000000.00
    0000114.77-
    0000367.78
    0290367.45
    0090367.26-
```

This column holds both positive and negative numbers. I need to convert this `LastAnalysisAmount` column values into decimal with correct format and load this into destination table.

For example, in the destination table, the values should be

```
     0.00
  -114.77
   367.78
290367.45
-90367.26
```

Can you please help me to write a SQL function to do this conversion?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Is data is present like this `0090367.26-` i.e negative sign at end of number?

Comment: The best way to fix this would be to stop storing numbers as characters. Then all you need is a little formatting.

Comment: @JaydipJ  .Yes 0090367.26- is a negative number

Comment: Sean Lange I load this data from the flat file into sql server staging table. So when bulk loading this into staging table, its is stored as varchar data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE()` and `TRIM()` with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LastAnalysisAmount LIKE '%-'
            THEN '-' + REPLACE(LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount),'-','')
            ELSE LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount)
        END as LastAnalysisAmount 
FROM YourTable
```

To load it as decimal to destination table:

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table (LastAnalysisAmount)
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN LastAnalysisAmount LIKE '%-'
                 THEN '-' + REPLACE(LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount),'-','')
                 ELSE LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount)
             END AS decimal(10,2))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this to load on Destination Table

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (LastAnalysisAmount)
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN RIGHT(LastAnalysisAmount,1) = '-'
                 THEN '-' + REPLACE(LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount),'-','')
                 ELSE LTRIM(LastAnalysisAmount)
             END AS decimal(10,2))
FROM from_table
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :** This will handle negative value case and convert it into `DECIMAL(8,2)`

```
SELECT CAST(
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',LastAnalysisAmount) > 0 
             THEN STUFF(LEFT(LastAnalysisAmount,LEN(LastAnalysisAmount)-1),1,0,'-')
             ELSE LastAnalysisAmount
             END AS DECIMAL(8,2)
         ) AS LastAnalysisAmount
```

Comment: then it means that value cast as `LastAnalysisAmount`. Right?

Comment: then it means that value cast as LastAnalysisAmount. Right? **Yes Exactly**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `varchar()` with a `case` sttaement:

```
select (case when LastAnalysisAmount like '%-'
             then '-' + replace(LastAnalysisAmount, '-', '')
             else LastAnalysisAmount
        end) as LastAnalysisAmount
```

If you want to send the data as a decimal, you can cast this to the appropriate type.

Comment: Shouldn't there be also a leading 0's trim(Either by string manipulation or casting) ? since OP wants the results without them.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you for the answer